# Why won't my function work when I use splice?

Tags: javascript, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to write a function which should calculate all prime numbers up to an input parameter and return it. I am doing this for practice.

I wrote this function in a few ways but I was trying to find new ways to do this for more practice and better performance. The last thing I tried was the code below:

```js
function primes(num){
  let s = []; // sieve
  for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
    s.push(i);
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

    for(let j = s[i]*s[i]; j <= num;) {
      //console.log(j);
      if(s.indexOf(j)!= -1){

        s.splice(s.indexOf(j), 1, 0);

      }
      j+=s[i];
    }
  }
  s = s.filter(a => a != 0);
  return s;
}
console.log(primes(10));
```

The problem is that when I run this in a browser it keeps calculating and won't stop and I don't know why.

Note: when I comment out the `splice` and uncomment `console.log(j);` everything works as expected and logs are the things they should be but with `splice`, the browser keep calculating and won't stop.

I am using the latest version of Chrome but I don't think that can have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
s.splice(s.indexOf(j), 1, 0);
```

`Splice` function third argument contains elements to be added in place of the removed elements. Which means that instead of removing elements, you are swapping their values with 0's, which then freezes your j-loop.
To fix it, simply omit third parameter.

```js
function primes(num){
  let s = []; // sieve
  for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
    s.push(i);
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

    for(let j = s[i]*s[i]; j <= num;) {
      //console.log(j);
      if(s.indexOf(j)!= -1){

        s.splice(s.indexOf(j), 1);

      }
      j+=s[i];
    }
  }
  return s;
}
console.log(primes(10));
```

Comment: doing this fix, you can also remove the `filter()` function in the end

Comment: @CalvinNunes Ofcourse you are right, i don't know how i didn't notice it. :)

Comment: ah, thanks. i actually did that first but i remember it didn't work i probably had another problem which i didn't catch at that time. and i thought maybe by changing the index in the array my for loop miss few numbers so i add the zero on purpose to avoid that. I am disappointed in my self :)).
thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this loop:

`for(let j = s[i]*s[i]; j <= num;)`

This for loop is looping forever because `j` is always less than or equal to `num` in whatever case you're testing. It is very difficult to determine exactly when this code will start looping infinitely because you are modifying the list as you loop.

In effect though, the `splice` command will be called setting some portion of the indexes in `s` to 0 which means that `j+=s[i]` will no longer get you out of the loop.

Comment: It's actually not difficult to realise when that code is going to loop infinetly. Its going to happen as soon as i-loop lands on an element that was previously swapped to 0 (`splice` third argument!), since by multiplying zeroes the condition `j <= num` will always be true.

Comment: Yes of course, but which indexes will be set to zero? Not so easy to reason about. In fact it seems there are at least two distinct situations where it could loop infinitely.

Comment: Well, in the current code you can already see it will stop as soon as `i = 2` (which means the element would be 4, but since its a multiplication of 2, it was previously set to 0)

Comment: Yes I see. I had to work out i = 0 and 1 to be convinced that it doesn't loop before that, just saying it's non-trivial to determine. It's clear just from looking at the code that the conditions will eventually be met though.

Comment: thanks. :)
i don't know why I didn't saw that. I am really disappointed in myself.